# Bootstrap control-group, controls class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

With Bootstrap implemented, what do `control-group` and `controls` class do when used inside form? And, does it only affect when they are nested in form element?

By the name, it seems to group controls that are assigned with the `control-group`
and apply some padding around it but when used outside form tag, it doesn't seem
to do anything.

Similar question arises with fieldset tag as it only seems to mean something when used with legend tag.

Comment: `control-group` has been superseded by `form-group` in Bootstrap 3 ([source](https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/issues/239)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you cannot use a form tag try using

```
<div class="form-horizontal"></div>
```

this will give you the alignment you are looking for

`form-horizontal` `form-inline` and `form` will give you options to change the layout flow of your page.

**Edit: Why?**

Lets say for example you would like to change how the form is displayed at different resolutions. Having the form class apply style to the child control-group you can use the same mark up and have it display different results by only changing the class attribute on the form. IMO it seems a much easier way then rewriting all of the dom elements surround your inputs/ labels.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. However, I don't have any problem with alignment, I just want to know the purpose of using `control-group` with `controls`and if it's only valid when used inside form element.

Comment: Hi @Kieran so, using `control-group` and `controls` are only valid inside form? Thanks again.

Comment: not sure what you mean by valid as it is just a css name. The selector looks like this .form-horizontal .control-group{/*apply rules*/}

Comment: What I meant is, if `control-group` and `controls` are used with normal div wrapper other than form, it becomes no use. right?

Comment: for controls yes. control-group has margin-bottom:10px;